# Different spacing in itemize when using Beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize, line-spacing

When using the following example, the second item has a little smaller spacing. Using the same code without Beamer (e.g., in article class) the spacing is equal.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Normal Spacing: long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long
    \item Some smaller Spacing: long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long
      \begin{itemize}
        \item Long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long
      \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The effect always occurs, when a sub itemize is following the item.

Answer (score 2):

Add an empty to line to force a new paragraph. Beamer changes the font for the nested list to \small before the list and this has side effects on the lines before.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{setspace,tikz}
\setstretch{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \tikz[overlay]\draw[red,<->](0,0)--(0,-18pt);Normal Spacing: long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long
    \item \tikz[overlay]\draw[red,<->](0,0)--(0,-18pt);Normal Spacing: long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long    

      \begin{itemize}
        \item Long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long
      \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]